# How to selectively update my local ubuntu mirror

Tags: updates, mirrors

Initially we have created a local ubuntu mirror and we update it manually as an when required. Now I need to selectively pick packages to be fetched from ubuntu mirror to our local mirror.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reprepro to do that: 
http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/

Docs on their site looks outdated but this wiki seems helpful: https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Reprepro

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use reprepro to maintain your repo.

Depending on your filtering needs, there two options to add to your `conf/updates` file:

[Generic](https://blog.sileht.net/create-a-smart-debian-repository-with-reprepro.html)

`FilterFormula: $Source (== openssl)`

Or

[Specific](https://lostwebsite.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/partial-debian-mirrors/)

`FilterList purge ../only_update_these_packages.txt`

Where the file contains a list of packages in `dpkg  --get-selections` format.